# What is the cause of AdsWarning 1861 after going into run mode in TwinCAT?

Tags: twincat

After trying to start the run mode, I get a fatal error on the target system :

> Init7\IO: Set State TComObj PREOP OP >> AdsWarning: 1861 (0x745, ADS
> ERROR: timeout elapsed)

Anyone of you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your target system running Windows 10? Has it recently been updated (Windows Update) to version 1803? If so, the problem is because TwinCAT is not compatible with the 1803-version of W10. Beckhoff did release an updated TwinCAT version 3.1.4022.20, but removed it as it caused other problems. They will release a new version in the coming days.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: Quick question: I am facing the same issue with Windows 10 1803. I am running 4022.4. I get the exact same error as OP. Do you know if this has been fixed in version 4022.22?

Comment: It's fixed in 4022.22.

Answer (score 1):

That often occurs when you have EtherCAT bus in the system and there are problems. For example you could have an EtherCAT slave configured and it is not found when trying to start the system. So check you I/O configuration.

Of course, the problem could also be the one that Jakob described.

Comment: In our case we have to turn off and then turn on again the EtherCAT Slave (PNOZ Multi Communication Module) so that slave connects again to EtherCAT bus.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into intermittent 1861 (0x745) errors with Twincat**2** on Win10 version **1809** communicating with a CX8090.  We did not see the intermittent 1861 errors on Win10 version **1709**.

Based off of [Jakob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645097/jakob), answer we tried updating the TcAdsDll.dll and AdsDll.dll from the latest [Twincat 2.11 x64 Engineering release install](https://www.beckhoff.com/english.asp?download/tcatdow.htm?id=159876032042844) (which was 2305) and it resolved our intermittent 1861 errors.

I'm not sure if anyone else out there still uses Twincat2, but this might help someone else searching for a solution to the 1861 error code.